# removeClass change not reflected on page

Tags: jquery, css

I am attempting to remove a CSS class from a particular DIV on-the-fly. I have the following jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.intro').click(function() {
            $('.row_2').removeClass('.last_row');
        });
    });
</script>
```

..with the following HTML

```
<div class="row_1 intro">Intro Row 1</div>
<div class"row_1 detail">Detail Row 1</div>
<div class="row_2 intro last_row">Intro Row 2</div>
<div class="row_2 detail last_row">Detail Row 2</div>
```

Conceptually, when the user clicks any of the `intro` DIVs it should remove the `last_row` class from the `row_2` DIVs. However, it doesn't seem to be working as the CSS styling applied to `last_row` on the rendered page is not removed from the `row_2` DIVs once the user clicks on the `intro` DIV.

Is this a problem with the jQuery code, or is there something else I need to do so that the relevant DIVs on the rendered page will update on-the-fly in response to the `last_row` class being removed?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `removeClass('last_row')` without the dot? Or is that valid, too?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: That's the answer, you should post it. Edit: Too slow :)

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Didn't mean to 'steal' your answer there, when I posted I didn't see any comments just yet.

Comment: @Björn: No worries, I'm really not very bothered who gives the answer, as long as there's at least one right answer in the end! :-)

Comment: Totally agreed. Some people though, you know..

Comment: Thanks all. Such a simple problem that kept me guessing for many hours :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$('.row_2').removeClass('last_row');` instead of `$('.row_2').removeClass('.last_row');` and it should work.

The argument passed to `.removeClass` should just be the name of the class, without the dot.

Answer (score 2):

`removeClass` takes a space-separated list of class names as its argument, so there's no dot:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.intro').click(function() {
     $('.row_2').removeClass('last_row');
  });
});
```

[See here](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) for details.

The "dot"-syntax is the *selector* mechanism that picks out the element.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

```
$("#amt").removeClass('hide');
```

did not make any difference; the field remained hidden.

I had to prefix the id with the "`body #form`" reference for it to work.

```
$("body #form #amt").removeClass('hide');
```

Worked, made the field visible. I understand that it is because, the page had more than one references to "#amt" and the first reference was always addressed resulting in the removeClass not working. Have to be specific, if there are more references to the same field. Hope this helps.